# Problems with using a dll in a access database

Tags: dll

What is the reason for this error in using dll??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD9CQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly->Check parameters!
The error says "No value given for one or more required parameters".
Then read this question (with answer), it may be helpful.
[No value given for one or more required parameters When all parameters are given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089297/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-when-all-parameters-are-given)